# graph library (c#) for Rete algorithm

Tags: c#-4.0, rete

Can you give me suggestions of graph libraries that are best to develop Rete algorithm.
I'm using .net 4.0
I found QuickGraph but I'm not sure if it's useful in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a C# dev, but I've implemented rete in another language. You want a directed acyclic graph algorithm, start looking [here](https://github.com/search?l=C%23&q=directed%20graph&ref=searchresults&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93) on github. Or perhaps [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/directed-acyclic-word-graph). However, you can get away with a simpler data structure with a visitor. And, if you haven't I'd read [Doorenbos, 1995](http://reports-archive.adm.cs.cmu.edu/anon/1995/CMU-CS-95-113.pdf), which will walk you through how to implement the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I agree with Chase. I have built a rules engine using Composite and Visitor, and its working absolutely flawless. Composite helps in organizing rules in a hierarchy (nesting) and Visitor helps you draw unlimited operations like evaluators, visualizers etc. I'd suggest building a truth logic first using composite and visitor and then wrap it up with expression parsing, where expressions are represented as text, maybe XML nodes, which naturally has the hierarchical structure to represent nesting of rules. Best is that you can version expression based rules.